# Trying to find out how my code goes wrong

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner learning Python and wrote the following codes. To control the loop flow I tried using a variable "test", but the loop never stopped. Appreciate if any thoughts.

```
test=False
while test==False:
    a=input("Please enter an even number to make test True: ")
    if int(a)%2==0:
        test==True
        print("test is now True")
    else:
        print("Please try again!")
```

Comment: `test==True` should be `test=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres the right code:

```
test=False
while test==False:
    a=input("Please enter an even number to make test True: ")
    if int(a)%2==0:
        test=True
        print("test is now True")
    else:
        print("Please try again!")
```

here's what you did wrong:

in the 5th line `test==True` the `==` checks if that's what the variable `true` stores, it doesn't set it; so this can be simply fixed by `test=True`

Answer (score 1):

```
test=False

while test is False:
    a=input("Please enter an even number to make test True: ")
    if int(a) %2 == 0:
        test = True
        print("test is now True")
    else:
        print("Please try again!")
```

Fixed the test == true, should've been test = true :) have fun learning